# Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured while starting App

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

The problem: My app opens up and shuts off before `ScrollTo()` command execution.

I got this error on Appium:

> 'Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured
>   while starting App. Original error:
>   com.disney.wdpro.android.mdx.activities.LoaderActivity or
>   com.disney.mdx.wdw.google.com.disney.wdpro.android.mdx.activities.LoaderActivity
>   never started'

Appium logs:

```
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\vovan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-
tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-
s","IRN7HITKLFOFVKK7","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` 
capability if wanted.
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured 
while starting App. Original error: 
com.disney.wdpro.android.mdx.activities.LoaderActivity 

orcom.disney.mdx.wdw.google.com.android.mdx.activities.LoaderActiv
ity never started
at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow 
(C:\Users\vovan\AppData\Local\Programs\appium- 
desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-
support\lib\logging.js:63:13)
at ADB.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\vovan\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-
desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-
adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:79:9)
```

Selenium Code Eclipse:

```
    public void test() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    File appDir = new File("src");
    File app = new File(appDir, "com.disney.mdx.wdw.google.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, 
    MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Device");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "50");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new 
    URL("http://169.254.159.242:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    driver.scrollTo("Get Started");
    TouchActions t = new TouchActions(driver);
    WebElement abc = 
    driver.findElementById("com.disney.mdx.wdw.google:id/tutorial_button");
    t.singleTap(abc).perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the desired capabilities, we need to pass the "appPackage" and "appActivity". Below are the complete desired activities that i have used in my project.

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","ANDROID");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName",Constant.appPlatform);
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", Constant.appPackage);
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",Constant.appActivity);
```

You can get the details of the appPackage and appActivity from developer or http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/how-to-find-apppackage-and-appactivity-for-apk-file/

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! How do you find appActivity ?

Comment: Weird. I have never used appPackage and appActivity and the tests for me have been running fine. Those are until needed if you want to open the specific Activity of the app, but if you just want to open the app then it isn't mandatory.

Comment: @SlavicTuro The easiest way is to check with your developer else use the link in my answer. Let me know if it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting app activty and and app package name is by typing : 'adb logcat' in command prompt.

At this point ,the app should be open in the connected device.Logs will be generated and the required app details can be fetched from there.

Comment: Also I try to run on emulator. I get this Appium logs:

'Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\vovan\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:63:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\vovan\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\apk-utils.js:186:9)'

Comment: I installed my app on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Another ways to get appPackage and appactivity.

1. Launch application in the device
2. Open Command prompt
3. Hit command 'adb devices' to make sure device is connected
4. Hit command adb shell
5. Hit command dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus

It will fetch appPackage for the opened app and activity which is currently opened